# Efficiently parse single digit arithmetic expression

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing

How would you efficiently (optimizing for runtime but also keeping space at a minimum) parse and evaluate a single digit arithmetic expression in Java.

The following arithmetic expressions are all valid:

```
eval("-5")=-5
eval("+4")=4
eval("4")=4
eval("-7+2-3")=-8
eval("5+7")=12
```

My approach is to iterate over all elements, keeping track of the current arithmetic operation using a flag, and evaluate digit by digit.

```
public int eval(String s){
    int result = 0;
    boolean add = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char current = s.charAt(i);
        if(current == '+'){
            add = true;
        } else if(current == '-'){
            add = false;
        } else {
            if(add){
                result +=  Character.getNumericValue(current);
            } else {
                result -= Character.getNumericValue(current);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is this the only optimal solution? I have tried to use stacks to keep track of the arithmetic operator, but I am not sure this is any more efficient. I also have not tried regular expressions. I only ask because I gave the above solution in an interview and was told it is sub-optimal.

Comment: Do you have a case like: eval("4+-5")?

Comment: @KrishnaSarma Yes, that is a possibility given the properties (e.g. eval("+5")=5 or eval("-4")=-4)

Comment: `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js").eval("-7+4")` only because I'm terribly lazy.

Comment: instead of working with strings you can use vectors, array list, or stack class which optimizes your code further. Generally we don't work with string much as they tend to take up more resources.

Comment: @NiteshVerma that's what I have trouble understanding. The only string operations which I am doing seem completely necessary since you have to parse each operation and digit from the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems a bit more compact. It certainly requires fewer lines and conditionals. The key is addition is the "default" behavior and each minus sign you encounter changes the sign of what you want to add; provided you remember to reset the sign after each addition.

```
public static int eval(String s){
    int result = 0;
    int sign = 1; 
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char current = s.charAt(i);
        switch (current)
        {
            case '+': break;
            case '-': sign *= -1; break;
            default: 
                result += sign * Character.getNumericValue(current);
                sign = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As a note, I don't think yours produces correct results for adding a negative, e.g., "4- -3". Your code produces 1, rather than the correct value of 7. On the other hand, mine allows expressions such as "5+-+-3", which would produce the result 8 (I suppose that's correct? :). However, you didn't list validation as a requirement and neither of us are checking for sequential digits, alpha characters, white space, etc. If we assume the data is properly formatted, the above implementation should work. I don't see how adding data structures (such as queues) could possibly be helpful here. I'm also assuming just addition and subtraction.

These test cases produce the following results:

```
System.out.println(eval("1+2+3+4"));
System.out.println(eval("1--3"));
System.out.println(eval("1+-3-2+4+-3"));

10
4
-3
```

Comment: I just tried this and I can't find a way for the function not to work properly. I would just do at first a regex check to be sure the parameter does not contain spaces or anything different rather than numbers or signs

Comment: This will only work if there is no operator precedence or parentheses.

Comment: I already mentioned I was assuming only addition and subtraction, in which case precedence doesn't matter; you evaluate left to right. None of the examples included anything other than addition and subtraction. 

Given that the inputs are restricted to a single digit, I'm assuming they do not want solutions involving regular expressions, which must be parsed and generally build suffix trees for the input. This requires a single (relatively fast) pass through the string. It is obviously not the "correct" way to evaluate general arithmetic expressions: not the question!

Comment: @Jeremy West: Who says regular expression require suffix trees? They don't. A properly compiled regular expression is a simple finite state automaton which parses the input in O(n) where n is length of the input string. Don't let you be mislead by popular regexp engines which have exponential(!) complexity in the worst case.

Comment: You can mention whatever you like, but unless the constraints you mention appear explicity in the OP's question, this is not an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup up 'recursive descent expression parser' or the Dijkstra shunting-yard algorithm. Your present approach is doomed to failure the moment you have to cope with operator precedence or parentheses. You also need to forget about regular expressions and resign yourself to writing a proper scanner.

Comment: Did you read the question? It was asked in an interview, where presumably they wanted code, and it was restricted to values with a single digit. I don't think they were looking for a full-featured parser.

Comment: It's not clear that you understand the issue here. 'Values with a single digit' has nothing to do with it. He needs an expression parser, unless there were other constraints, not mentioned. This is the answer I would give, and if they told me that was 'suboptimal' I would walk, having implemented it in compilers dozens of times. Conversely, if I was the interviewer, (a) I wouldn't be asking such a question, as I would be quite prepared to *train* a candidate with suitable aptitude, but (b) anyone providing an answer without a stack of some kind would be shown the door.

Comment: Nope, I definitely understand the issue here.