# bc utility in java, fails for some cases

Tags: java, bc, postfix-operator

I am trying to write simple bc utility in java. My program works fine for most cases but is failing for expression 4+4*3-3-2-1/3. basically consecutive - operators. not sure if i covered all edge cases. any suggestions to make it better would be very helpful.  Thanks

```
//ENUM for operations allowed.
private enum Operators {
    ADD         (1, "+"),
    SUBTRACT   (1, "-"),
    MULTIPLY    (2, "*"),
    DIVIDE      (2, "/");

    String operator;
    // Operator priority
    int weight;
    Operators(int w, String o) {
        this.operator = o;
        this.weight = w;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
// Stack and Queue to convert expression to postfix
LinkedList<String> resultQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
Stack<Operators> operatorStack = new Stack<Operators>();
//Stack to evaluate postfix expression
Stack<Integer> evalStack = new Stack<Integer>();

public int eval(String exp) {
    char[] expChar = exp.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (i < expChar.length){
        if (expChar[i] >= '0' && expChar[i] <= '9') {
            sb.append(expChar[i]);

            if (i == expChar.length - 1) {
                resultQueue.add(sb.toString());
                while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()){
                    resultQueue.add(operatorStack.pop().getOperator());
                }
            }
        } else if (expChar[i] == '+' || expChar[i] == '-' || expChar[i] == '/' || expChar[i] == '*'){
            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                resultQueue.add(sb.toString());
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
                pushOperator(expChar[i]);
        } else
        return 0;
        i++;
    }
    for (String r : resultQueue){
        if (r.charAt(0) > '0' && r.charAt(0) < '9'){
            evalStack.push(Integer.valueOf(r));
        }else {
            try {
                int op2 = evalStack.pop();
                int op1 = evalStack.pop();
                if (r.charAt(0) == '+')
                    evalStack.push(Integer.valueOf(op1+op2));
                else if (r.charAt(0) == '-')
                    evalStack.push(Integer.valueOf(op1-op2));
                else if (r.charAt(0) == '/')
                    evalStack.push(Integer.valueOf(op1/op2));
                else if (r.charAt(0) == '*')
                    evalStack.push(Integer.valueOf(op1*op2));
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Parse Error");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    int result=0;
    try{
        result = evalStack.pop();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Parse Error");
    }

    return result;
}

private void pushOperator(char c) {
    Operators val = getOperator(c);
    if (operatorStack.isEmpty() || val.getWeight() >= operatorStack.peek().getWeight()){
        operatorStack.push(val);
    } else {
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && val.getWeight() <= operatorStack.peek().getWeight()){
            resultQueue.add(operatorStack.pop().getOperator());
        }
        operatorStack.push(val);
    }
}

private Operators getOperator(char c) {
    for (Operators o: Operators.values()){
        if (o.getOperator().equals(String.valueOf(c)))
            return o;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator not supported");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BC bc = new BC();
    System.out.println("Please enter expression: ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String exp = scn.nextLine();
    //remove white spaces
    exp = exp.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println("Result: " + bc.eval(exp));
    scn.close();
}
```

Comment: anyone?? just need to solve for case 5-4-1, consecutive subtraction. Cant seem to get my way around it. think rest cases are covered

Comment: Have a look at those SO answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755532/efficiently-parse-single-digit-arithmetic-expression. Either take the lazy one `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js").eval("4+4*3-3-2-1/3").toString()` or have a look at the accepted answer. Both could help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I should be able to evaluate by postfix expression itself. mine is a simple expression and imitation of BC utility in unix. i do not need to accept consecutive operators. I should be able to make a fix in way i push elements in stack to correct behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for consecutive minus operations you compute in the wrong direction. You compute from right to left whereas your need to computer from left to right.

If you have on the stack the operants `12 3 2 0 - - -` you compute effectively

```
12 - (3 - (2 - 0)) = 11
```

wheras correct would be

```
12 - (3 + 2 + 0) = 7
```

One possible soulution to fix it would be. Just before you start the computation you need to change the operants on the stack to `12 3 2 0 + + -`.

See this snippet which could be executed before the computation loop.

```
// your code
...
    }
    i++;
}

for (i = 0; i < resultQueue.size() - 1; i++) {
    if ("-".equals(resultQueue.get(i)) && "-".equals(resultQueue.get(i+1))) {
        resultQueue.set(i, "+");
    }
}

// your code
for (String r : resultQueue) {
    if (r.charAt(0) > '0' && r.charAt(0) < '9') {
...
```